# How to autostart pygtk program after boot

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I am working on python program in Ubuntu that checks the Internet connection and display a image on top panel using GTK and PYGTK module. Now i am trying to autostart my python program after booting.Please help me.

I tried autostart in `/etc/rc.local` but its showing this type of error.....

```
GtkWarning: could not open display

Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

GtkWarning: IA__gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_number: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
```

Comment: If your program needs to display on a user's desktop, then in should be started after user login rather than as part of the boot process: see [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)